# Text to speech in objective-c iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, text-to-speech, speech

I am developing an application in which I have to play string as an audio.

I am using http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello API to speak the string but it is a little bit slow.

Is there any library in objective-c to play string as an audio "Text To Speech".

Comment: Is this a iOS app or MAC OSX app? because objective-c does have some way to play string audio I guess.

Comment: visit this [link](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
not so sure but it may work for you :)

Comment: Yes, OpenEars is a perfect candidate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at the classes AVSpeechUtterance  and AVSpeechSynthesizer in io7. Basically you can just do the following.

```
     AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
     AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init]autorelease];
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: But how can I do for iOS 6 ?

Comment: Ssml is supported or not?

Answer (score 11):

import frameworks :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

.m file code

```
NSString *str = @"Hello friend, how are you?";

AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

AVSpeechUtterance *speechutt = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:strtext];
 speechutt.volume=90.0f;
 speechutt.rate=0.50f;
 speechutt.pitchMultiplier=0.80f;
[speechutt setRate:0.3f];
speechutt.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-us"];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:speechutt];
```

voiceWithLanguage option in any language to speek supported that.

```
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) - ar-SA
Chinese (China) - zh-CN
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) - zh-HK
Chinese (Taiwan) - zh-TW
Czech (Czech Republic) - cs-CZ
Danish (Denmark) - da-DK
Dutch (Belgium) - nl-BE
Dutch (Netherlands) - nl-NL
English (Australia) - en-AU
English (Ireland) - en-IE
English (South Africa) - en-ZA
English (United Kingdom) - en-GB
English (United States) - en-US
French (Canada) - fr-CA
French (France) - fr-FR
Finnish (Finland) - fi-FI
German (Germany) - de-DE
Hindi (India) - hi-IN
Hungarian (Hungary) - hu-HU
Indonesian (Indonesia) - id-ID
Italian (Italy) - it-IT
Japanese (Japan) - ja-JP
Korean (South Korea) - ko-KR
Norwegian (Norway) - no-NO
Romanian (Romania) - ro-RO
Russian (Russia) - ru-RU
Slovak (Slovakia) - sk-SK
Spanish (Mexico) - es-MX
Swedish (Sweden) - sv-SE
Turkish (Turkey) - tr-TR
```

Comment: it posible audio to text ?

Comment: i don't know ,sorry

Comment: it ok p.j.Radadiya

Comment: how to stop AVSpeechUtterance and voice if out of apps

Comment: // This stops the speech synthesizer immediately.
[speechSynthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
// And this would continue it.
[speechSynthesizer continueSpeaking]

Answer (score 0):

The Nuance [NDEV Mobile iOS SDK](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=prodDev) could be your best bet, in terms of quality and performance, but unlike OpenEars is not free. That said, we've got 40 different languages and 61 different voices available, and the library has a subsystem that doesn't rely on HTTP (and is still network based) that you can play with.

Once you've signed up for an account..

- Create an application with the intent to use the iOS platform
- Download the iOS SDK (there's a sample app in there, but i'll describe the process to integrate it into your app)
- Import the SpeechKit.framework, and associated frameworks (see [docs](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/Basics.html#using-speech-kit))
- Specify the credentials from the info from the app created above
- Initialize `SpeechKit` with that information
- Create a `Vocalizer` instance, specifying the language or voice
- Use that `Vocalizer` instance to `speakString` with the text you want to synthesize
- Handle the delegate methods:

  - `willBeginSpeakingString:(NSString *)text`
  - `didFinishSpeakingString:(NSString *)text`

Note: The Vocalizer API also supports [SSML](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/).

Comment: Hi Nirvana, is there any option to set the vocal duration in Nuance?